# Django Rest Framework nested object response

Tags: django, object, nested, response, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django Rest Framework, I am trying to implement Comment System API,
I have model like this

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    parent_id = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)
```

where parent_id is used for replies.

If Parent_id is greater than 0 that means the current comment is a reply to some other comment. Now I want to use Django Rest Framework to have JSON response like this :

```
 [
   {
    "id": 10,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "content": "Test Comment",
    "likes": 1,
    replies : [ 
              { "id": 11,
                "parent_id": 10,
                "content": " Reply 1 Test Comment",
                "likes": 1,
              },
              { "id": 12,
                "parent_id": 10,
                "content": " Reply 2 Test Comment",
                "likes": 1,
              }] 
   }
]
```

Can someone help me with how to make such a response?
I am using Django 1.7.6 and Django Rest Framework 3.1.1

Comment: I would highly recommend using a recursive `ForeignKey("self")` in your `Comment` model instead of storing just the `parent_id`.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, it helps me. Created nested serialized class of Comment and it works form me.. Again thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you have the `Replies` model like this:

```
class Replies(models.Model):
    comment = Models.Foreignkey(Comment)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Then you could use `rest_framework.serializers.ModelSerializer` class (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer):

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class RepliesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Replies
        fields = ('id', 'content', 'parent_id', 'likes')
    parent_id = serializers.Field(source='comment.parent_id')

class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('id', 'parent_id', 'content', 'likes', 'replies')
    replies = RepliesSerializer(many=True)
```

Comment: I don't have Replies model. Comment model it self contains reply, based on parent_id, we identify comment is reply or normal comment.