# Django: How to get all users with profiles as JSON (extended User model)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I have extended the default User model in Django. Now my models look like following:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
birth_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, default=datetime.now)
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True, default="")
address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default="")
organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, blank=True, null=True)
```

Everything works fine, I am able to add new users through admin panel and so on.
However, I have got a problem. I need to return a customize JSON response to certain request in form of:

```
[
{"firs_name": first_name, "phone_number": phone_number, ...},
{"firs_name": first_name, "phone_number": phone_number, ...},
...
]
```

As you can see, the `phone_number` attribute belongs to the Profile model, and I cannot get ALL users with their Profiles included (I am able to get only id of user).
Here is the response I get for now:

```
[{"username": "user", "profile": 2, "first_name": "User", "last_name": "User"}, {"username": "user1", "profile": 3, "first_name": "User1", "last_name": "User1"}, {"username": "user2", "profile": 4, "first_name": "User2", "last_name": "User2"}]
```

Question: Is there any way to get all user objects with profile information included in it through `User.Objects.all()`?

Thanks!

P.S.:
This is how I make custom JSON response:

```
def get_users_as_json(request):
all_users = User.objects.all().values("username", "first_name", "last_name", 'profile')
user_list = list(all_users)
return JsonResponse(user_list, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no.of ways to Do so , try these

```
def get_users_as_json(request):
    col = ["username", "first_name", "last_name", 'profile_id', \
    'profile__phone_number', 'profile__address_no', 'profile__birth_date']

    all_users = User.objects.all().values(*col)
    user_list = list(all_users)
    return JsonResponse(user_list, safe=False)

def get_user_as_json(request):
    user_list = []
    users = User.objects.all()
    for user in users:
        user_dict = {}
        user_dict['user_name'] = user.username
        user_dict['first_name'] = user.first_name
        user_dict['phone_number'] = user.profile.phone_number
        user_dict['birthdate'] = user.profile.birth_date
        ...

        user_list.append(user_dict)

    user_list = list(user_list)
    return JsonResponse(user_list, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Django-rest-framework and then just repeat this instruction [Django Rest Framework nested object response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591287/django-rest-framework-nested-object-response)

I will recommend you to read about how to extend Django user model because it looks like you model Profile is just extended User model
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user

Answer (score 0):

You could just enter all the variables you want manually

```
User.objects.all()
    .select_related('profile')
    .values_list('username', ..., 'profile__phone_number', 'profile__address'...)
```

Comment: Yes! I used it as User.objects.all().values('profile__phone_number'). Thank you!